# How do I signify repetition in a ZMV regex?

Tags: regex, zsh, batch-rename

I'm trying to manually pull the digests off of Rails assets (don't ask). I was directed to ZMV for easy regex-based find/replace. But the normal `{32}` syntax for specifying an amount of repetition does not work:

```
$ zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//-[A-Za-z0-9]\{32\}/}'
```

I've tried some other formats. This, for example, works, but is too greedy (it will turn `image-3.png` into `image.png`, for example):

```
$ zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//-[A-Za-z0-9]##\./.}'
```

That double-hash syntax only showed up after a lot of Googling (I'd have expected `+`). But I cannot for the life of me find how to make `{32}` work. I tried `#32#`? Which appeared to work, but that's because it was reading it as (in my eyes) `?32?` and that means it met anything that had a three in the digest or last character.

How do I signify character repetition in zmv?

EDIT:

Apparently it would help some to view filenames I'm trying to match? To be clear: **my question is "how do I signify character repetition in zmv"** *not* "how do I match these filenames" (a question I know the answer to in standard RegEx format). If it helps, here is my intended before and after:

```
directory/asset-jej4jtifne9bjkkeuwr09rewrewlur23.css
another-directory/style-748reiodlpqwerntaerwerwerexfzsdf.js.gz
directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing-qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456.js
third-directory/should-not-match-3.css
```

Should become:

```
directory/asset.css
another-directory/style.js.gz
directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing.js
third-directory/should-not-match-3.css
```

SECOND EDIT:

Because I needed to do this yesterday, I did it the long way and (as expected) it worked. I'd still like to know how to avoid it in the future. Here's the command I ended up using (I repeated my character matcher 32 times explicitly):

```
$ zmv '(***/)(*)' '$1${2//-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]/}'
```

THIRD EDIT:

For the record, I'm using zsh on OS X. I'd imagine zmv is the same across platforms, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a list of input files and your desired output. You need to explain what you are trying to match, not just give a regex that may or may not do what you need.

Comment: @terdon I think that clouds the question, as my RegEx *already matches*  the filenames as expected on sites like rubular.com or in Ruby, JS, etc., and my question is *how do I do this in zmv*, but I've added them if it helps.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to check because i) most users don't actually know much about regexes and ii) so I could have something to play around with and see if I could figure it out. By the way, while this is perfectly on topic here, in the future, you might want to consider asking such questions on [unix.se] instead. There's a much higher concentration of CLI junkies there, including quite a few zsh experts.

Comment: Good to know. I wasn't sure - I spend pretty much all my time on StackOverflow but this didn't seem right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shells mostly don't provide the usual regexp syntax, but wildcard “glob” patterns. Basic shell wildcards aren't as powerful as regular expressions; for example, the regexp `.*` (any sequence of characters) is equivalent to the glob pattern `*` but the regexp `a*` (any sequence of `a`'s) has no glob pattern equivalent in plain sh. See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for an overview of the main different regexp/pattern syntaxes.

Zsh has [zsh extended glob patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) which provides the same expressive power as regular expressions  but with different syntax. These patterns are automatically enabled in `zmv` and in completion functions, but elsewhere in zsh they need to be enabled explicitly with `setopt extended_glob` (put that in your `.zshrc` — the only reason it isn't the default is backward compatibility with ancient versions of zsh).

There is a repeat-N-times syntax, but it's a bit hidden, listed under [globbing flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags) rather than under the list of operators. It's the `c` flag, which must be used alone, followed by the number of repetition (or two comma-separated numbers to give a range).

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${2//-[A-Za-z0-9](#c32)/}'
```

Comment: `(#c32)` is what I was looking for! Awesome! Thanks so much. I really need to read up on globs in general.

Comment: PS I think the postfix `#` wouldn't be what I was looking for because it would match the `should-not-match-3.css` file, and remove `-3`, which I didn't want.

Comment: Last comment: "Why does my regular expression work in X but not Y" is an amazing resource that I've been seeking for years. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it to work with `zmv` either. There must be a way but it escapes me. However, `zmv` is not the only tool that can do something like that. You can also use `rename`.

- If you're using `zsh`

  ```
  $ rename -n 's/-[A-Za-z0-9]{32}//' **/* 
  another-directory/style-748reiodlpqwerntaerwerwerexfzsdf.js.gz renamed as another-directory/style.js.gz
  directory/asset-jej4jtifne9bjkkeuwr09rewrewlur23.css renamed as directory/asset.css
  directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing-qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456.js renamed as directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing.js
  ```
- If you're using `bash`

  ```
  $ shopt -s globstar 
  $ rename -n 's/-[A-Za-z0-9]{32}//' **/* 
  another-directory/style-748reiodlpqwerntaerwerwerexfzsdf.js.gz renamed as another-directory/style.js.gz
  directory/asset-jej4jtifne9bjkkeuwr09rewrewlur23.css renamed as directory/asset.css
  directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing-qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456.js renamed as directory/subdirectory/this-is-a-thing.js
  ```

Note that there are two `rename` commands in the Linux world. The examples above use the Perl one which is the default on Debian-based distributions.

---

The reason you couldn't get this to work with `zmv` is that i) it's not `zmv` that interprets the expression, that's a shell feature and therefore ii) that's not a regular expression at all, it's a glob.

When you run the command in your question, `zmv` sets `$2` to each of the file names and then it's the shell that runs the replacement (`${2//...`). Once the variable has been expanded by the shell, it is returned to `zmv` which attempts the rename operation.

Like the korn shell and bash, zsh [supports](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html) the `${foo//bar}` format which will remove all matches of the glob `bar` from the variable `$foo` (contrast it with `${foo/bar}` which will only remove the first match). It works like this:

```
% foo="Xababab"
% echo ${foo//ab}
X
% echo ${foo//a*b}
X
```

As you can see above, the patterns are globs and not regular expressions. The *glob* `a*b` means "match `a`, then 0 or more characters and then `b`". It is the equivalent of this regular expression: `a.*b`. <del>Globs, unlike regexes, don't support repetition</del> (Apparently, zsh's globs do, see [Gilles's answer](https://superuser.com/a/894828/151431)). The `x{n}` syntax will not match n repetitions of x. This, therefore is why your regex failed: it wasn't being interpreted as a regex at all!

Comment: In my googling I saw suggestions to use `rename` but zsh doesn't recognize that for me – probably because I'm in OS X, not Linux. I'll add that detail above. Some more googling tells me I can just `brew install rename`, which would've saved me all this trouble. Upvoting because this solves my actual problem. I'd still like to know if there's a way to do this *in zmv*.

Comment: @BenSaufley yeah, me too now. It's strange that none of the obvious solutions work. I asked one of our resident zsh experts on U&L in chat and gave the link to this Q. We'll see if he responds. Seriously though, next time you have a zsh related question, do ask on U&L. We have a couple of zsh fanatics there who'll always answer zsh questions and who are ridiculously knowledgeable about it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I definitely will. There's so much to learn!

Comment: @BenSaufley I figured it out. I should have realized sooner, that's not a regex, it's a glob and globs don't do repetitions. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! I had a hunch there was something like that going on, but a bunch of resources (apparently incorrectly) refer to this method as "zmv with regular expressions," and in fact a bunch of RegEx functionality does work. TIL. Thanks again!

Comment: @BenSaufley nah, it's even [mentioned](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) in the docs: "The pattern is always treated as an EXTENDED_GLOB pattern." And you're very welcome :)

Comment: Zsh's globs do support repetition, unlike plain sh.

Comment: @BenSaufley the expert I called on responded. Please feel free to accept his answer since he does provide the way to do it using the tools you wanted.